# How to Add a new step in checkout step, I want add new tab After shipping methods tab and before payment tabs in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, module, checkout-page, checkoutsession

I'am working  with magento 1.9, Now i want add new tab in checkout steps.
I want add new tab between shipping methods and payment method information.
I want add custom "mytabs" between two tabs with 2 to 3 custom fields.
 I want tabs like

**"shipping methods"
  "Mycustom new tab"
  "payment method information"**